# Why aren't iOS10 user notifications firing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I've taken this code directly from Apple's page: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent. I've place it in viewDidLoad(). `UserNotifications` has been imported.

It compiles, the app runs, breakpoints in the code are hit but no notification. I'm using Xcode 8 (not beta) and targeting iOS10.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Hello!"
content.body = "Hello_message_body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
// Deliver the notification in five seconds.
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "2", content: content, trigger: trigger)

// Deliver the notification in five seconds.
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger)

// Schedule the notification.
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
center.addNotificationRequest(request)
```

Comment: yes - I watched the WWDC video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test only on the device, and check your settings like crazy. In particular:

- Be sure you've asked the user for authorization. If you have no authorization, you won't get any notifications for this app. If you never saw the authorization dialog, that's the problem here.
- Even if the authorization dialog appeared and you tapped Allow, there are a lot of Notification settings that can prevent your notification alert from appearing in various places.
- Be sure to look in the notification center. Do Not Disturb will turn off the sound and the alert, but it will appear in the notification center unless Notification settings forbid.
- Be sure to give yourself enough time after `center.addNotificationRequest` to get out of your app, since unless you take steps to the contrary, the notification alert will not appear when your app is frontmost. Your intervals are pretty short.

Comment: sigh...can't run it on the device because Xcode says I have no developer accounts. When I click add account, I can see my developer account is clearly listed.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a different problem. But I believe I've answered the question you asked. I can give you a full working example project if you like! Just let me know.

Comment: It is. I've posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551125/how-to-add-xcode-code-signing if you have any suggestions. I can't really test anything on the device until that is working. Please post your sample. I'd like to try it anyway.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch13p630localNotification Seems to work okay on simulator too, actually. See what you think. As I said, I think my answer above covers all bases; I'll be very surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are doing with such a complex example.

Comment: Finally got it working on the simulator but not while in the app like you did. How are you getting them to trigger in the app?

Comment: Tap the button, wait 10 seconds. You think the example is complex?? It makes one local notification that fires once, that's all.

Comment: yeah - it's overly complex for that. Or maybe over engineered is a better word. I have my notification code in viewDidLoad. Notification doesn't appear unless I get out of the app before the allotted time.

Comment: Well, that's what I said in my answer. :) I don't agree that the example is over-engineered. Everything I'm doing is something you must do at some point, and I'm taking care to illustrate everything that might need illustration, including custom interface extension. However, keep in mind that this is not an independent teaching example; it accompanies my book, where all the code is discussed and explained in detail. In other words, the rationale for the construction of the example lies in the _book discussion_; the example code is not meant to be self-explanatory.

Comment: Ddi you ever manage to resolve this? I am having a similar problem, although I am working in Objective C. I have found that if I omit the trigger (pass nil) that the notification fires and the banner appears (immediately of course), but if I use a trigger the app just doesn't receive the notification at all. I don't know if this provides a clue to anyone, but I am tearing my hair out. I checked the nextTriggerDate after creating the trigger, and everything looks good, and the notification is added successfully, it just doesn't fire.

Comment: @GarethClarke When I managed to persuade the OP to just download and run my example, and not keep messing with it and trying to change it all around, he discovered that my example works fine. So there is nothing to solve. To him, the example was "over-engineered", but as I said in my answer, there is a lot of stuff you have to do in order to get this to work right, and my example does them.